# Making the second and third OpenFileDialog appear above the console in .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console, openfiledialog

I'm writing a console program that can accept 1 to 3 files. I'm using `OpenFileDialog` three times to accept the files, but the second and third time the file dialog is behind the console window, making it hard to notice. Any way to get it to appear above?

An image of the problem:

[image]

The relevant code is:

```
static bool loadFile(ref List<string> ls)
{
    OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded file {0}", f.FileName);
        ls.Add(f.FileName);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // sanity check
    if (args.Length > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this program currently supports a maximum of three different reports to analyze at a time.");
        return;
    }
    else if (args.Length == 0) 
    {
        List<string> fL = new List<string>();

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            if (!loadFile(ref fL)) break;
        }

        if (fL.Count == 0)
        {
            InfoDisplay.HelpMessage();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            args = fL.ToArray();
        }
    }

    // main program
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but the OpenFileDialog has a property called "MultiSelect" which indicates whether or not the user can select more than one file. Once the user does select the file(s), the property FileNames (string[]) gets populated with all the file names. You can then just do a check like this:

```
if(dialog.FileNames.Length > 3)
{
   //only 3 are allowed
}
```

Comment: right, but i'm  afraid  the user would not know that and just select a single file while wanting to load 2 or 3. or the files are in different locations, making it difficult to load all three withmultiselect.

Comment: Fair enough, but from a user's perspective, I think getting prompted with three consecutive Dialog's would be quote annoying. Perhaps you can consider a form with three textboxes and three Browse buttons. I personally think that would be a bit more user friendly IMO.

Comment: well the thing is, i made a gui version and a console version.for some reason the console version is 10x faster despite using the same code for the main processing...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in a console application.

OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog can be called with a "parent window" handle argument. I create a dummy Form and use that as parent window argument (the dummy form is invisible, since I don't call Show() on it).

The following code works for me:

```
Form dummyForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();

OpenFileDialog myOpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();  
if (myOpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(dummyForm) == DialogResult.OK) {  
    fileName1 = myOpenFileDialog1.FileName;  
}

OpenFileDialog myOpenFileDialog2 = new OpenFileDialog();
if (myOpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog(dummyForm) == DialogResult.OK) {
    fileName2 = myOpenFileDialog2.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, dummy forms and label still didn't solve the problem.  CodeProject has a partial solution at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MessageBox.aspx

You can then use `Process.GetCurrent.Process.MainWindowHandle` in the constructor to the class in the article above, then pass the instance to the file dialog, and it seems to work well (for me at least).

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
WindowWrapper w = new WindowWrapper(p.MainWindowHandle);
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
var ret = ofd.ShowDialog(w);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar post [here](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/e8433d49-442c-4fc0-bef3-031f126b01c6/).  Not tested, but give it a shot and let me know.

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses)
{
    if(p.MainWindowTitle = <the main UI form caption>)
    {
        if(IsIconic(p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32) != 0)
        {
            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32, &H1);
            ShowWindow(f.Handle.ToInt32, &H1);
        }
        else
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32);
            SetForegroundWindow(f.Handle.ToInt32);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog does not contain a definition for BringToFront....

Comment: I think I'm missing some references...system.threading?

also, openfiledialog doesnt contain a definition for Handle.

Comment: Hmm bummer, I'm not at my IDE sadly, just thought I would try to answer this one straight away.  The only thing I can think to do would be create a form that shows the open dialog on Load, closes when the dialog closes, and passes the dialog result back.  But that's really ugly and a hack applied to hack, so I really don't recommend it.

Comment: yeah, im not sure why this happens. the first openfiledialog appears just fine. also, i tried hiding the console window, but the 2nd and third openfiledialogs decide to have the lowest z-order of all my programs, so they can only been seen if i minimize everything...

Comment: what's worse is that i know it can be done. i have a program called turbotop, which if you tell it the  name of the openfiledialog, will make it appear on top. now if only i can do that natively in c#...

Answer (score 0):

> OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog can be
>   called with a "parent window" handle
>   argument. I create a dummy Form and
>   use that as parent window argument
>   (the dummy form is invisible, since I
>   don't call Show() on it).

The Form is a bit heavy-weight, perhaps a label instead, since it just takes a IWin32Window?

```
OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(new Label());
```

It seems to work.

If someone could come up with a reasonable solution to this (now-) resurrected question, that would be great.

Aaron